# XCode: find all missing project files

Tags: macos, xcode

is there any way I can create a list of all missing files in an XCode project?

I have inherited a project with thousands of files, but quite a few are missing. Building the project only informs me of a subset of the missing files at a time, so it'll take a while to do it manually.

I've found a way to convert the pbxproj file to XML so I will try writing some code to do it. I also found a Java project to read and parse pbxproj files, but it's unusably slow: https://github.com/mestevens/xcode-project-parser

Happy with an OS X or Windows solution.

Comment: This is actually a bad question for SO.  So hopefully we are not thinking of migrating it there.

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea why you would say that. I chose to ask it on superuser because it seemed like the best fit.

Comment: Read my comment; never said it wasn't in the correct place but 3 migration votes might indicate otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Ruby library to parse the pbxproj file, and a Ruby script to find which files were missing:

https://github.com/mjmsmith/pbxplorer